# Setting the background that works with background changing script

Tags: javascript, css

I have a script to change the background of a page when I hover over text, but how do I set the background when the page first loads?

Thanks if you can help.

html:

```
<div class="bg1">
<p style="background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/tsvMD.jpg)" onMouseOver="bgChange('http://i.imgur.com/tsvMD.jpg')">001</p>
<p style="background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/WoXUM.jpg)" onMouseOver="bgChange('http://i.imgur.com/WoXUM.jpg')">002</p>
<p style="background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/Q5U1L.jpg)" onMouseOver="bgChange('http://i.imgur.com/Q5U1L.jpg')">003</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.bg1 p {
display:inline;
font-size: 30px;
}
```

javascript:

```
function bgChange(bg)
{
document.body.background=bg;
}
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/XXwXq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css.. ?

```
body {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/tsvMD.jpg);
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XXwXq/13/

```
function bgChange(bg) {
   document.body.style.background="url(" + bg + ")";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that won't work with the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line below the bgchange function:

```
window.onload=bgChange('http://i.imgur.com/Q5U1L.jpg');
```

So it would be:

```
function bgChange(bg)
{
    document.body.background=bg;
}
window.onload=bgChange('http://i.imgur.com/Q5U1L.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS and the "background-image":

```
body {
  background-image:url(...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that doesn't seem to work with the javascript.